# Add query string to URL if there is none already

Tags: php, jquery

I have a question. My question title doesn't really describe what I need help with, but it's the same concept. This is what I want to do:
I am creating a search function (not open for other suggestions than the one I am trying to accomplish), and it's using query string. If I search for "Hello", I want my website to redirect to website.com?s=hello, but if there already is one, add it to the url with a &, like this: website.com?page=home&s=hello. 
I tried to use this:

```
if(isset($_GET)) { // Add the string with & before
else { // Add the string with a ? before
```

I am willing to use jQuery if I **have** to

More brief explanation:
I have a form, it has an input and a submit-button.

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <li><input type="text" placeholder="Username"></li>
    <li><input type="submit" value="Search"></li>
</form>
```

I am aware how to store everything in variables and such, but I am not sure how to add it as a query string to the url. Thank you!

Comment: Provide more code, particularly the HTML. If I understood correctly, in your form (which I am assuming you are using), store the values of your query string in hidden inputs.

Comment: I updated the code, thank you for telling me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A way to do it is to handle it in php in your form:

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET['page'])) {
    $url = '?page=' . $_GET['page'];
}else {
    $url = '';
}

?>
<form method="GET" action="<?= $url ?>" >
    Search <input type="text" name="s" />
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>`
```

Note that if you want to submit your form AND go to the page ?s=foo as a result of submission, you must have a method GET on your form and have an input with argument name="s".

**EDIT:** Or a bit more exhaustive, if you have several arg that could be passed in the URL it could be :

```
<?php
if(!empty($_GET)) {

    $url = '?' . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
}else {
    $url = '';
}
?>

<form method="GET" action="<?= $url ?>" >
    Search <input type="text" name="s" />
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your reply! But this isn't what I was looking for :( I want the query string to be relative to whether there already is one! So if there already is one defined, add &s=(string), and if there is not, add ?s=(string), do you understand? Thank you! :)

Comment: Yes and that's what it will do ^^. Look, in php you check if the user is on a given page by checking the $_GET['page'], if the user is on yourdomain.com/?page=home the $url var value will be '?page=home' then the action in the form will be action="?page=home" and then, by searching "(string)" then clicking on the submit button, it will redirect you automatically to "yourdomain.com/?page=home&s=(string)

Comment: I edited my answer to be more exhaustive in the url possibilities.